# Ruby to PHP AES

Tags: php, ruby, aes, sha256, cbc-mode

Im trying to convert some ruby code that encrypts data with AES 265 in CBC mode to php but its not working, the converted php code returns a null string. Here is what i have:

Ruby:

```
require 'openssl'

module AESCrypt
  def self.encrypt(message, password)
    Base64.encode64(self.encrypt_data(message.to_s.strip, self.key_digest(password), nil, "AES-256-CBC"))
  end

  def self.decrypt(message, password)
    base64_decoded = Base64.decode64(message.to_s.strip)
    self.decrypt_data(base64_decoded, self.key_digest(password), nil, "AES-256-CBC")
  end

  def self.key_digest(password)
    OpenSSL::Digest::SHA256.new(password).digest
  end

def self.decrypt_data(encrypted_data, key, iv, cipher_type)
    aes = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new(cipher_type)
    aes.decrypt
    aes.key = key
    aes.iv = iv if iv != nil
    aes.update(encrypted_data) + aes.final  
  end

def self.encrypt_data(data, key, iv, cipher_type)
    aes = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new(cipher_type)
    aes.encrypt
    aes.key = key
    aes.iv = iv if iv != nil
    aes.update(data) + aes.final      
  end
end
```

And the php code:

```
echo base64_encode($encrypted_data = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, hash('sha256', 'p4ssw0rd'), 'hey', MCRYPT_MODE_CBC));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have a look at

https://github.com/nirnanaaa/xlix/blob/master/xlix/lib/Xlix/Bundle/Crypto/Aes/TwoLevel.php

I wrote this a while ago for my crypto functions based on a GIST I have found on the web